# How to build matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sift

I'm looking for building a matrix of an image descriptron extracted from SIFT.
I got the descriptor's locations (X,Y), and I want to build the patch 15X15 pixels.

```
--------------------------------
(144,100)|      |       |      |
--------------------------------
         |      |       |      |
--------------------------------
         |      |       |      |
--------------------------------
```

Is there any way to store the locations X and Y in one cell in a matrix. I dont know how to store the result.

Comment: I think you're looking for a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)...

Comment: Or just a 3D array such that `A(:,:,1)` are the X values and `A(:,:,2)` are the Y values